# For firebase rules, why does permission get denied at uid level?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I got this error in the console

> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /people/cQEVsQGXS3VJQzPBU4nL1HLx0Kq2 failed: permission_denied

Here are my rules below. I have an idea that the error might be at uid, because of the console message that I got, but I am not sure. I used the firebase documentation to try to figure out how to write the rules.

```
{
"rules": {
  "people" : {
    "$uid":  {
      "Education" :{
         ".read": "auth.uid != null" 
        ,".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
      ,"Coordinates" : {
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }  
      ,"ForReUpload": {
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
      ,"PhotoPosts": {
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
        
      ,"WhatIamConsideringBuying":  { 
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
      ,"caption": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
      ,"peopleWhoLike" : {
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
      }
      ,"peopleWhoLike2" : {
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
      }
     
      ,"postID" : { 
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
      ,"users" : {     
         ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
       ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"  
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Here is a JSON of my db:

```
"people" : {
"1ZWT7FAE2qThNQfBj7tbMO7BnMo1" : {
  "Coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : 50.054738,
    "longitude" : 8.226809826085624
  "peopleWhoLike2" : {
    "1vLVFwrXrHUoakmDrnQKwbv08Yj1" : 1581548952597,
    "F9NX0UCG4fVHCKFk2VZ1NZKsLro2" : 1586210112155,
    "IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1" : 1581547417432,
```

Triggering query:

```
    let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid //Mr. Dunn's uid
    
    refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");
    
    refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in
        
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            
            self.people.removeAll()
            
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                
                    if people.key != thisUsersUid {
                        print("peoplekey",people.key)
                        

               
                    let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
                      let locCoord = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                      let distance = locCoord.distance(from: self.dict)
                            print(distance, "distancexy")




....
   self.people.append(peopl)
  .....

   self.people.sort { ($0.distance ?? 0) < ($1.distance ?? 0) }

           print("aaaaaaaa", self.people.map {$0.distance})
                
           self.table.reloadData()

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query that's failing, and what you expect it to do instead.  It should be clear how your query matches your rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read from `/people/cQEVsQGXS3VJQzPBU4nL1HLx0Kq2`, but your rules don't grant anyone read access to that path.

I think you're looking for these much simpler rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "people" : {
      "$uid":  {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you want to allow only certain child node, you'd typically use validation rules for that. Something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "people" : {
      "$uid":  {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid",
        "Education" :{ ".validate": true },
        "Coordinates" : { ".validate": true },
        "ForReUpload": { ".validate": true },
        "PhotoPosts": { ".validate": true },
        "WhatIamConsideringBuying":  { ".validate": true },
        "caption": { ".validate": true },
        "peopleWhoLike" : { ".validate": true },
        "peopleWhoLike2" : { ".validate": true },     
        "postID" : { ".validate": true },
        "users" : { ".validate": true },
        "$other" : { ".validate": false },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above allows all the named child nodes, but rejects all others (thanks to the `$other` rule).

Comment: Thanks. But what about Childs like PeopleWhoLike PeopleWhoLike2. They need write ability to other users. Wouldn't the last settings in your answer only give write access to current logged in user("$uid == auth.uid")?

Comment: Ah, if you need broader access for one of the nodes, you can still do that after the change I proposed here. But the error message you posted came from trying to read a node that nobody has access to, which is what I tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: @ Frank van Puffelen  Thanks. I tried the top one a few days ago and it I remember it rejected the Childs on account of people having no rules. That is also how I understand your answer, ie that rules don't grant access to people. That issue would also apply to the second example. In the second example, would they ever get to the Childs like education, because uid and people have no rules (like my initial attempt)

Comment: These rules allow access to `/people/$uid`, so any user-specific node for a known user. Whether that works for you depends on where you are trying to read from, which you haven't shown (Doug asked for that code in the comments btw). If you're trying to read from all of `/people`, you'll need to define a `.read` rule there to grant access.

Comment: Thanks. My bad. I missed Doug's comment. I just added one of the triggering queries. Other are more specific, like snapshot of Childs, not snapshots of people. The one in the example is a snapshot that ends in people (ie doesn't go as far as the Childs) because multiple Childs are needed to append and reload.

Comment: Yeah, since you attach a listener on `people`, you need to grant read access on that node too. Firebase rules don't filter the data for you, but merely check if the operation is allowed. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters and many of the [questions mentioning that 'rules are not filters'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+rules+are+not+filters)